# How can i filter fancy texts in python

Tags: python

I have a simple script in python copy text and paste another place
i wanna Prevent Copy if a text have fancy character like bottom

Ｈｅｌｌｏ
ℌ

> Must Skip Emojies and legal characters (Arabic & English)

How can it possible as easiest way

Comment: Please [edit] to be _specific_ on what is "fancy". Do you mean only allow Arabic and English?

Answer (score 3):

with the built in string function `.isascii()`, if the string contains anything that is not ascii, it will return false, example:

```
# if text is ascii or is arabic or is imojie print True else print false

text = 'هلا hala'
print(all((ord(c) < 128709 and ord(c) > 127568) or (ord(c) < 1609 and ord(c) > 1568) or c.isascii() for c in text)) # True

text = ' موز '
print(all((ord(c) < 128709 and ord(c) > 127568) or (ord(c) < 1609 and ord(c) > 1568) or c.isascii() for c in text)) # True

text = ''
print(all((ord(c) < 128709 and ord(c) > 127568) or (ord(c) < 1609 and ord(c) > 1568 ) or c.isascii() for c in text)) # True

text = 'love '
print(all((ord(c) < 128709 and ord(c) > 127568) or (ord(c) < 1609 and ord(c) > 1568 ) or c.isascii() for c in text)) # True

text = 'banana'
print(all((ord(c) < 128709 and ord(c) > 127568) or (ord(c) < 1609 and ord(c) > 1568 ) or c.isascii() for c in text)) # True

text = 'Ｈｅｌｌｏ ℌ '
print(all((ord(c) < 128709 and ord(c) > 127568) or (ord(c) < 1609 and ord(c) > 1568 ) or c.isascii() for c in text)) # False
```

Comment: it will filter Arabic Characters + Emojies, it only accepts English and symbols

Comment: sorry for the delay i didn't understand the assignment correctly, i have updated the answer to fulfil your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I'll explore this a bit before giving a solution. Firstly lets look into the ASCII for normal alphabets

```
ord("A"), ord("Z"), ord("a"), ord("z")
    
(65, 90, 97, 122)
```

The ASCII numbers between 90 and 97 are for brackets, or other such instances if i'm not wrong.

Coming to fancy text, this is what I found.

```
ord("ᴇ")
    
7431
```

Hence I think its safe to say that if your string has an ASCII outside the range from before, then its probably styled, and you can put a condition to skip it.